# Using numpy arrays for division

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, math

For the numpy function below why can I not get the expected output below. I get the same value of `25.00187514` as the output for all of the 3 variables inputted. I was expecting to get `[25.026178010471202,  25.0 , 25.02994011976048]` instead how would I be able to do that?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([0.47753582 0.52503938 0.41753131])
b = np.array([19.1 21.  16.7])
result= (a* 1000) / b
```

Output:

```
[25.00187514 25.00187514 25.00187514]
```

Expected Output:

```
print((0.478 * 1000) / 19.1, (0.525 * 1000) / 21.0, (0.418 * 1000) / 16.7)

25.026178010471202,  25.0 , 25.02994011976048
```

Comment: That's not valid python...

Comment: `0.52503938*1000/21` is **not** `25`. Your expectation is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [44]: a = np.array([0.47753582, 0.52503938, 0.41753131])
    ...: b = np.array([19.1, 21.0, 16.7])
    ...: result = (a * 1000) / b
In [45]: result
Out[45]: array([25.00187539, 25.00187524, 25.00187485])
In [46]: (0.478 * 1000) / 19.1, (0.525 * 1000) / 21.0, (0.418 * 1000) / 16.7
Out[46]: (25.026178010471202, 25.0, 25.02994011976048)
```

[46] is different from `result` because the numerators have been rounded.

Looks like the `a` values have created with:

```
In [48]: b * 25.00187514 / 1000
Out[48]: array([0.47753582, 0.52503938, 0.41753131])

In [49]: b * 25.00187514 / 1000 - a
Out[49]: array([-4.82599999e-09, -2.06000006e-09,  4.83799995e-09])
In [50]: result - 25.00187514
Out[50]: array([ 2.52670155e-07,  9.80952422e-08, -2.89700598e-07])
```

Comment: yea you are right I misunderstood

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([0.47753582, 0.52503938, 0.41753131], dtype=np.float128)
b = np.array([19.1, 21.,  16.7])
result = (a*1000 ) / b
print(result)
```

It uses `np.float128` datatype which allows for better precision.

Comment: there is no `np.float128` value on numpy

Comment: I still get the same output `[25.00187514 25.00187514 25.00187514]`

Comment: @bullselcuk. There is, just not on your machine maybe